# Server side rendering and client side rendering

Tags: server, client, rendering

I want to check is my website server side rendering or client side rendering or partial. How can i check that? I know SSR is recommended for SEO and other reasons. I think there is some way to do that using inspect element if i am not wrong?

Thanks

I want to see my website's content is Server Side rendered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.